# JavaScript alert on orientation change keeps refiring forever on Android

Tags: javascript, android, device-orientation

This code creates an alert when the orientation of a mobile device is changed. It works fine for my iPhone but on my Android the alert keeps firing, effectively making the page unviable. The code is run on dom ready.

```
function orientation() {

    alert('orientation change');
    // return false;
}   
window.onorientationchange = orientation;
```

Any one have any idea why this is happening? Incase there's a solution using it im using jQuery for this site. Thanks

UPDATE - this code does exactly the same thing:

```
var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window, orientationEvent =     supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

  window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
     alert ('orientation changed');
  }, false);
```

Comment: have you tried returning `false`?

Comment: I tried adding it (see my updated question) without the comments, but Im getting the same issue.